# Removing all empty p-Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i need your help with an regex in Javascript, again.

Sometimes i have empty p-Tags in the DOM and i will remove them all.

Some look like:

```
<p></p>
```

others like:

```
<p> </p>
```

I think for an regex pro is this very lame, but i'm not good with it :(

so thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Yepp i don't get the point. Why do you want to do this, Save bandwidth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for something this simple. Most likely you need to iterate over all the 'p' elements anyway. Something like this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/3pV2P/

```
$('p').each(function(index, item) {
    if($.trim($(item).text()) === "") {
        $(item).slideUp(); // $(item).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: i'd prefer `if(!$(item).text().trim()) { ... }`

Comment: Working fine, but not usable in IE cause dont know the trim function

Comment: @Yepp - Thanks for the heads-up! I have updated the example to use jQuery's `trim()` function.

Comment: @mqchen, one caveat in your code is that if the 'p' element only contained an image link with no text, it would be removed. For instance: <p><a href="someaddress"><img src="someaddress"></a></p>

Answer (score 4):

A very basic regex for this:

```
<p>\s*<\/p>
```

And here's a [simple RegEx Tester for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regular-expressions-tester/) that might help you in the future. I use it quite a bit.

Comment: Please edit your question to add that you also want the code to remove the empty nodes - that's not clear from the question as it is. Also might to want to add that you use jQuery, as that's only in the tags so far and I assumed you didn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

that's some methods that helps sometimes

```
$('p:empty').hide()
p:empty { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is of course completely correct but since the poster asked for how to use regular expressions, here is a regex version (for completeness if you will) that does just that:

```
$('p').map(function() {
   if( /^[\s ]*$/.test($(this).text()) ) {
      $(this).remove();
   }    
});
```

Note a better regex version can be achieved by using the jQuery [regex selector extension](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)